# Download link is undefined when getting bytes stream in Angular

Tags: angular, download, pdf-generation, angular-promise, bytestream

I'm trying to generate a PDF file from an endpoint, the showPDF function has an ID parameter of the Product and generate a PDF as an output.

I've tried to declare a Promise to get the bytes stream from that endpoint:

```
    showPdf(rowData: Product) {

    console.log("ID = >" + rowData.id);

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let apiURL = this.apiUrl + "/api/products/get/pdf/"+rowData.id;
      this.http.get(apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => { // Success
       
        this.results = String(res);
        console.log("Bytes=> " + res);
       
        resolve();
        },
        msg => { // Error
        reject(msg);
        }
      );
  });  
    const bytes = this.results; 
    const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ bytes;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = "Report.pdf";

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    console.log("downloadLink = >" + downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

The issue is that the downloadlink is executed before getting the result from the Promise.

For instance, when calling showPDF(942) I get an undefined value of the download link

[image]

When calling showPDF for the same ID or another ID value, it generates the PDF but from the previous bytes stream value got from the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
showPdf(rowData: Product) {
    console.log("ID = >" + rowData.id);
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let apiURL = this.apiUrl + "/api/products/get/pdf/"+rowData.id;
      this.http.get(apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => { // Success

        this.results = String(res);
        console.log("Bytes=> " + res);
// here after getting the result we are calling the another function to download the PDF
        this.downLoadPdf();
        resolve();
        },
        msg => { // Error
        reject(msg);
    }
   );
  });  
}

downLoadPdf() {
    const bytes = this.results; 
    const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ bytes;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = "Report.pdf";

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    console.log("downloadLink = >" + downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I'm calling the function downloadPDF, it works : the PDF file is generated with the right download link value, however the generation process is very slow, while the first code generate the PDF instantly

Comment: @Angelika Yes because it is waiting for the API call to complete